# Why Javascript file is working only for "about"?

Tags: javascript, html

I have: about, calculator, contact and I want to create one function for all of the elements, but during testing, it works only for the first element. Thanks for the help!

```js
let tool = document.querySelector(".tool");

tool.onclick = function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.id);
};
```

```html
<ul class="tools">
  <li class="tool" id="about"><i class="fas fa-question blue"></i> - about</li>
  <li class="tool" id="contact"><i class="fas fa-phone blue"></i> - contact</li>
  <li class="tool" id="calculator"><i class="fas fa-calculator blue"></i> - calculator</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `querySelectorAll` for selecting all the elements with the provided `class` name and iterate over them and binding your click handler.

```js
let tools = document.querySelectorAll(".tool");
for (var i = 0; i < tools.length; i++) {
  tools[i].onclick = function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.id);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="tools">
  <li class="tool" id="about"><i class="fas fa-question blue"></i> - about</li>
  <li class="tool" id="contact"><i class="fas fa-phone blue"></i> - contact</li>
  <li class="tool" id="calculator"><i class="fas fa-calculator blue"></i> - calculator</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. But then my javascript doesn`t work, I need a cycle?

Comment: Oh, I understand, sorry

Answer (score 0):

See  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

> The Document method querySelector() returns the **first** Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors.

and

> If you need a list of all elements matching the specified selectors, you should use querySelectorAll() instead.

But see also: [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)